# Process.Kill() returns access denied

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to kill a process using a CMD command line from my C# application but when i start the application nothing happens... When i try to kill from command prompt i recieve the message: "Access denied". I've tried to run my app as Administrator and the process was killed. How can i manage not to always use "Run as Administrator"?

Code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C taskkill /F /IM APP.EXE";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
```

Comment: To be able to kill any program you must have enough privileges to it. You can normally only kill processes that belong to you. For example, you can't kill programs started as administrator or system processes, not at least without elevating yourself. To clarify, what is the intended "victim"?

Comment: The process is from and application that requires UAC when started so i think that this is the problem... Is just a simple app, not a "victim" .

Comment: Yeah, "victim" is just a funny way to say that :P. Ok, but if the target program is run with elevated privileges, it follows that *any* other program that wants to manipulate it must also use elevated privileges, at least for this particular case. Even if you try it with task manager, you must elevate it too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.UserName = "Administrator";
        startInfo.Password = <password>;
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C taskkill /F /IM APP.EXE";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

Comment: This app its supposed to be on more machines.

Comment: @Yildirim check David Pilkington answer ! You can add /user:Administrator to the Arguments but you will be always asked for the passowrd

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this in the manifest

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true"/>
```

Comment: @Yildirim I am not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

It's means that your application was ran under administrator, so you can kill it only under administrator too.
Try too launch application under another user.

Hope this help.